# Auto-input 'y' when prompted in command-line from Java

Tags: java, batch-file

The program I'm using runs through the command prompt from java using a batch file (following the solutions from [Run .exe file from Java from file location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685893/run-exe-file-from-java-from-file-location), and at one point of time, it will prompt the user for an input which is either a 'y' or 'n' in order to continue the program.

How do I program using java codes such that the value 'y' or 'n' is automatically entered when prompted, without requiring users to enter it manually? I have tried using pipe (following the solutions from [How do you enter something at a DOS prompt Programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457406/how-do-you-enter-something-at-a-dos-prompt-programmatically)) but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Grab the [`InputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) from the [`Process`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) and write the `y` into it.

Look at this questions for example code:

- [Java Process with Input/Output Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643939/java-process-with-input-output-stream)
- [Reading streams from java Runtime.exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343066/reading-streams-from-java-runtime-exec)

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I am new to Java so I am a bit confused with the terms used. Based on my understanding of your answer, it means to use the InputStream and the BufferedReader to read the line and finally to use System.out.println to write 'y' into that line?

Comment: No. You have to write to the (wrapped) `InputStream` you get from the process. `System.out.println` always prints to the console.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the old DOS way.

Create a file, say **yes.txt**. All it should have is **y** (as per your app expectations). *The file can contain responses to multiple prompts each on their own lines*

Now you can execute your exe file something like this

```
myApp.exe < yes.txt
```

When exe prompts, yes.txt will supply the prompt text

Comment: Do I include that "myApp.exe < yes.txt" under the batch file or after the Runtime and Process?

Comment: You have to write a batch file with "myApp.exe < yes.txt" and call the batch file from within java program